# Calendar.app fails to correctly display starting time of appointment when synced with google calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Note the time difference in the screenshot of Calendar.app.

[image]

The appointment has been created directly on the google calendar webapp. It starts at `9.00` and ends at `10.00`.

After syncing with Calendar.app it shows up as you can see in the screenshot.

The detail information on the appointment is one hour too early. This happens reproducibly every time I create a new appointment.

Calendar.app: `Version 8.0 (2032.6.1)` 
OSX: `10.10.2 (14C109)`

Answer (score 1):

Switching off timezone support fixes the display problems:

`Calendar Preferences > Advanced > Uncheck Time Zone Support`